# problem with docker container creating a VPN tunnel

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to make an OpenVPN server using docker I just started creating a tunnel between 2 containers after installing openvpn on both container the command :

```
openvpn --dev tun1 --ifconfig 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2
```

gave me this error:

```
Mon Jul 12 12:26:28 2021 disabling NCP mode (--ncp-disable) because not in P2MP client or server mode
Mon Jul 12 12:26:28 2021 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Apr 27 2021
Mon Jul 12 12:26:28 2021 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020, LZO 2.10
Mon Jul 12 12:26:28 2021 ******* WARNING *******: All encryption and authentication features disabled -- All data will be tunnelled as clear text and will not be protected against man-in-the-middle changes. PLEASE DO RECONSIDER THIS CONFIGURATION!
Mon Jul 12 12:26:28 2021 ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)
Mon Jul 12 12:26:28 2021 Exiting due to fatal error
```

is the problem related to working on a container?
is it fine to make a OpenVPN server on a ubuntu image-based container?
if there is any other tips to make an OpenVPN server please tell me I'm new in this topic.